# Websphere query string encoding issue

Tags: servlets, character-encoding, websphere, url-encoding

Have an URL with non-latin symbols in query params:[http://localhost:9080/proxy-octopus/oct2c/!adm_v2_Common.DialogForm?func=FiltrProc&title=Поиск процедур по набору атрибутов](http://localhost:9080/proxy-octopus/oct2c/!adm_v2_Common.DialogForm?func=FiltrProc&title=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%20%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Changed url encoding for WAS to Windows-1251: client.encoding.override set to Windows-1251

Query parameters are got good. Next code returns valid value: "Поиск процедур по набору атрибутов".

```
request.getParameter("title")
```

But for next code I've got valid value: "func=FiltrProc&title=Ïîèñê%20ïðîöåäóð%20ïî%20íàáîðó%20àòðèáóòîâ".

```
request.getQueryString()
```

Also I can receive real value ("func=FiltrProc&title=Поиск%20процедур%20по%20набору%20атрибутов") by next way:

```
new String(request.getQueryString().getBytes(Charsets.ISO_8859_1),"Windows-1251")
```

What I must do to receive valid value on request.getQueryString()?

Answer (score 0):

For internationalization it is more reliable to use UTF-8 encoding.

So, try to change client.encoding.override to UTF-8.

Also, check if your title parameter is properly url-encoded.

Comment: Can't change to UTF-8 because I've got legacy application with Windows-1251 encoding. If tittle is not properly encoded, I wouldn't be able to get properties by request.getParameter("title") method, would me?

Comment: You mean source code in 1251? Can you convert all the source code to UTF-8 and use the UTF-8 on the WAS? Seams request.getQueryString() uses default encoding.

Comment: It's **legacy** project so I can't change it's encoding.

Comment: Seams like. But I've overrided "client.encoding.override" so all must be OK. That all my question: What I am wrong.